# Angular7: Any way to limit the scope of multiple of the same components on the same page?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, hook

I'm putting multiple of the same component on a page, and they are all receiving input. When one of these inputs get changed, they all refresh! Is there any way to not have it all refresh?

```
<tr *ngFor="let map of imgs | keyvalue; index as i;">
    <td><app-preview [file]="map.value"></app-preview></td>
</tr>
```

Component:

```
<img *ngIf="src" [src]="src" alt="">
```

The component should be being sent different map values, but when one map value changes, all of the components refresh, it looks very bad.

Comment: Can you share some code example to better understand your use case ? It is behaving as expected where if you are using same components multiple times on a page and the components binds to some `@Input` property, changing that property is going to update all the component instances.

Comment: I see two separate components i.e. `app-preview` and `img`. Not able to relate to your issue with this code.

Comment: sorry i added more

Comment: No problem. So if I understand correctly, your do not want other `app-preview` components to refresh when the input `map.value` for one of them changes ?

Comment: Yes, when I delete a map.value, it shouldn't refresh all the components. They are all different.

Comment: Take a look into the `trackBy` function along with your `ngFor`. This way you can better control the change propagation which causes the refresh. https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation

Answer (score 2):

This is the scenario where we should use the trackedBy function.

Modify your code as follows.

In your html,

```
<tr *ngFor="let map of imgs | keyvalue; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <td><app-preview [file]="map.value"></app-preview></td>
</tr>
```

And in your ts file

```
public trackByFn(index, item) {
    if(!item) return null;
    return index;
}
```

This will **avoid** re-rendering the entire list in the dom when your list get updated. The default trackBy is done using the references of objects and change
it to trackBy your index of the list so that the entire dom will not get update. So... **will enhance your performance**.

For more information, take a look at [this](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5)